# javascript: sorting through objects that have objects and reading them

Tags: javascript

How does this code read for reading through an object, able to read objects within it:

```
var book = {
    "main title": "Javascript",
    "sub-title": "Def Guide",
    "for": "all audiences",
    author: {
        firstname: "David",
        surname: "Fatagans"
    }
};

for (propName in book){
    console.log("key: " + propName + " value: " + book[propName]);
    if (typeof book[propName] === "object"){
        for (innerObject in book[propName]){
            console.log("key: " + innerObject + "value: " + book[propName][innerObject])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FStatements%2Ffor...in

Comment: **@nick:** Read this sentence aloud _How does this code read for reading through an object, able to read objects within it._ Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: Yeah, basically if the value of an object is an object, it will be able to read that nested object.  Just wondering if this was a good attempt at checking for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to put the code into a function and call it recursively, something like:

```
function printObject(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    console.log("key: " + propName + " value: " + obj[propName]);

    if (typeof obj[propName] == "object") {
        printObject(obj);
    }
  }
}
```

The above will also show enumerable attributes on the object's `[[Prototype]]` chain. To ignore those, use a *hasOwnProperty* test:

```
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
    // propName is not inherited
  }
```

Be careful with passing host objects (e.g. DOM elements) to the function, extra precautions need to be taken with those.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Been reading the Flanagan book and this is right in there.